# How to access sprockets/coffee script assets from a plugin in the ror3 host application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, assets, sprockets

Imagine a rails engine with a /app/assets/javascripts/my_engine.js.coffee.
I use the engine as a gem in the Gemfile.

What would I have to do, to be able to access "my_engine.js" from the consuming host? In the (my) best case it would directly enter the host's application.js without any further editing on the host side...

Any ideas? I tried looking this up on the internets, but so far I could not find anything that explains it (and I guess that this functionality ia more or less the point of the whole sprocket/asset pipeline).

On a very different note it is odd that I get so few responses lately...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already solved this, but for anyone else who comes across this.

Within your Applications /app/assets/javascripts/application.js file you add:

```
//= require my_engine
```